# Can one make a predicate function from a Plumatic Schema?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

I want to make a predicate function that when something matches schema X returns true, else false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`schema/check`](http://plumatic.github.io/schema/schema.core.html#var-check) which works like [`schema/validate`](http://plumatic.github.io/schema/schema.core.html#var-validate) but returns errors directly as a value instead of throwing exception or `nil` when no errors are found:

```
(schema/defschema string-vector
  [schema/Str])

(defn str-vec? [arg]
  (nil? (schema/check string-vector arg)))

(str-vec? ["hi"])   ; => true
(str-vec? ["hi" 5]) ; => false
```

There is also `schema/checker` which "compiles an efficient checker for schema":

```
(let [str-vec?-checker (schema/checker string-vector)]
  (defn str-vec? [arg]
    (nil? (str-vec?-checker arg))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most beautiful solution, but we can use schemas `validate` and catch the exception it throws on failures.

```
(schema/defschema string-vector
  [schema/Str])

(defn str-vec? [arg]
  (try (schema/validate string-vector arg)
       true
       (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
         false)))

(str-vec? ["hi"])   ; => true
(str-vec? ["hi" 5]) ; => false
```

Hopefully someone else can provide a better solution.